# Laravel 5.3 Validation Fails when Variables are Null

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

Since upgrading laravel from 5.1 to 5.3, I've got couple of odd issues with Validation.

When I post a data like this:

```
firstName    null
```

And the validation rules are like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($postData, [
              'firstName'           => 'string|max:255',
              'lastName'            => 'string|max:255'
            ]);
```

The above fails with the messages something like `"The XYZ must be a string."`. What I don't understand is:

1. Why is the validation failing when it is not set as `required`?
   Meaning, it should ignore it and not throw an error if the value is
   empty, right?
2. Why does the validation fail if the value is set as `null`?
3. Why does the validation fail when the parameter is not sent at all?
   (like the `lastName` which is not posted at all)

Has something changed in Laravel 5.3 validations?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Add [`nullable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-nullable) rule:

```
'firstName' => 'string|max:255|nullable',
'lastName' => 'string|max:255|nullable'
```

> The field under validation may be `null`. This is particularly useful when validating primitive such as strings and integers that can contain `null` values.

Comment: Perfect. That fixed it. Thank you! I will accept your answer in 10 mins once SO allows me to. A quick question, did this change in laravel 5.3? Cuz I did not get this issue in 5.1 and I never added nullable in validation rules.

Comment: @Neel  don't see any code for `nullable` rule in 5.2. It's in 5.3 only. So I guess they changed something in validation.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much @Alexey for pointing this out. It was very helpful!

Comment: doesn't work for dates

Answer (score 9):

When you want something to be **required** but the value itself **can** be empty, like an empty string.

```
Validator::make($postData, [
          'firstName'           => 'present|string|max:255|nullable',
          'lastName'            => 'present|string|max:255|nullable'
        ]);
```

Useful in scenarios like "notes", which can be emptied by removing the input field from all its text and hit save.